# MVC & SQL: Cannot insert the value NULL into column, after migrating to new database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to insert values into a table via a MVC webpage. When I was running the webpage off of the localDB generated by Visual Studio this error did not occur.  Since I migrated to a remote database I am now getting this error.

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DRTReviewerId', table 'FC.Developer_Schema.DRTReviewers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Here is the offending piece of code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "DRTReviewerId,Name")] DRTReviewer dRTReviewer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.DRTReviewers.Add(dRTReviewer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(dRTReviewer);
    }
```

The value for DRTReviewerId should be a int generated by the code but since I switched databases this is no longer occurring.  What could have caused this change?

The code was completely generated using entity framework. My knowledge MVC is beginner at best.

Comment: the two databases (local DB and server DB) clearly don't have an identical structure. Check the table schema of the remote DB to see if it corresponds with what entity framework is expecting. You will probably find that the DRTReviewerId column is marked "not null", i.e. null values are not allowed. It sounds like this is the PK field of the table and ought to be marked as an auto-increment field in the table design. (It's not normally the C# code that produces this kind of ID, but the database engine).

Comment: Alternatively, if you're expecting the ID field to be supplied from the C# code, you need to either (a) ensure a value is in fact being passed to the DB, or (b) if empty IDs are permitted, mark the field nullable (you can check your local DB to compare against and see what's different)

Comment: I have it set as the primary key but how do I set it to auto increment?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%20set%20column%20auto%20increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table in the remote database have either a primary key or unique key created for "DRTReviewerId" column. Hence it is not accepting nulls. Update the table schema in remote DB.

To make a primary key auto increment, you have to set the Identity Specification->Is Identity to true and Identity Increment to 1(In DRTReviewerId column properties).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would wrap the db.SaveChanges() in try catch to see the detailed error information:

```
try{
       db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException vex)
{
       // Write to log file if you have logging support 
       Debug.WriteLine(HandleDbEntityValidationException(vex));
       throw;
}
catch (DbUpdateException dbu)
{
       // Write to log if you have logging support
       Debug.WriteLine( HandleDbUpdateException(dbu));
       throw;
}
```

Comment: that might help with debugging but it's not really an answer to the actual problem

Comment: @ADyson: I know it helps with debugging and I think that is what we are doing here (figuring out why savechanges is throwing exception). I feel its the best way to figure out quickly what is going on in case of working with remote boxes.